# Regarding "link" tag in HTML what is the most used value for the "rel" attribute after "stylesheet"?

Tags: html, css

I know "stylesheet" us used the most but I was wondering if other values are used and how much are they used. I personally did not encounter other values besides "stylesheet" until now.

Comment: Googling could solve the problem.

Comment: I googled and found other attribute values. I am curious how often are they used. That is why i asked on a programmer forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `icon` is must be the second most used since many sites use a favicon.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Have you ever used another value besides those 2 ?

Comment: `rel=author` is another one I have seen a lot. It helps author name appear in Google search results.

Comment: And if you put author what do you write in the href attribute?

Comment: Thats a separate question which I would appreciate if you ask as another question.

Comment: i did ask the question.